# subclassing UITableView so it doesn't need a xib

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I made a XIB that only consisted of a UITableView in IB.  It was brought to my attention that it is possible to subclass UITableViewController and do away with the xib entirely.

My question is, how do you do this?

So far the only thing I have changed is my .h to be...

```
   @interface MyView : UITableViewController
```

and removed my XIB.  Obviously I get an error that states

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with <path>
 name 'MyView''
```

so my question is, what else is left in order to accomplish this subclassing correctly?

Comment: Did you delete the `MyView.xib` from the project and clean the project?

Comment: yes.  I removed the xibs and then did a clean.  *edit* ok apparently now I am getting a 'could not load nib in bundle'

Comment: Where are you allocating `MyView`? Something is trying to point it at your old xib file.

Comment: When a button is pressed, I run this line of code for the allocation.  `MyView *myview = [[MyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

Comment: you should not initWithNibName. You should initWithStyle: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ok, Simon pointed me in the right direction.  I changed my initialization line from above to `MyView *myview = [[MyView alloc] init]"`

Comment: MyView is a very misleading name for your class. You should consider something like MyTableViewController.

Comment: @atreat that both fixes and answers my followup question about grouping.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @rmaddy - thats not the real name of my view, i edited it out for simplicity.

Comment: BTW - The Table View Programming Guide for iOS shows how to do all of this in code. I recommend you read through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to set up your view controller in iOS.

- With a .xib file: You instantiate the view controller with `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, passing the name of your .xib file as the first argument, and (unless you're doing some advanced stuff) `nil` as the second argument . The OS will look for your .xib file and unserialize it into a bunch of objects and attach them to your view controller. Then the OS calls your view controller subclass's `-viewDidLoad:` method, where you finish setting things up.
- Programmatically: You instantiate the view controller with `-init`, or for a table view controller, `initWithStyle:`. The OS then calls your subclass's `-loadView` method, where you manually instantiate your view hierarchy.

It sounds like you just need to instantiate it with `-initWithStyle:` instead of `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a ViewController without a .xib you could just create a tableview in the view did load or something.

```
UITableView *table = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
table.dataSource = self;
table.delegate = self;
table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:table];
```

And then you just need to implement the proper delegate and data source methods like you would in a UITableViewController.